# Sending an email with Mutt

Tags: linux, email, mutt

I'm trying to send an email with mutt but get an error like so:

> TLSv1.2 connection using TLSv1/SSLv3 (ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256)
>   SASL authentication failed
>   Debugging at level 5.
>   Could not send the
>   message.

My mutt config (~/.muttrc):

> set ssl_force_tls=yes
>   set from = "mulligun81@gmail.com"
>   set realname = "Darek"
>   set imap_user = "mulligun81@gmail.com"
>   set imap_pass = "asmd0077"
>   set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993"
>   set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
>   set postponed ="+[Gmail]/Drafts"
>   set header_cache =~/.mutt/cache/headers
>   set message_cachedir =~/.mutt/cache/bodies
>   set certificate_file =~/.mutt/certificates
>   set smtp_url = "smtps://mulligun81@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465/"
>   set smtp_pass = "asmd0077"
>   set move = no
>   set imap_keepalive = 900

As suggested elsewhere i've

- gnutls-bin (gnutls-3.4.13)
- openssl (openssl-1.0.2h)
- libsasl2 (cyrus-sasl-2.1.26)

installed.

PS.
Why doesn't the debug option gives any info?

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to post your Gmail password here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to switch authentication to OAuth2 in your muttrc  - [doc](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#oauth)

1. Use the oauth2.py script from Google's [gmail-oauth2-tools](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/blob/master/python/oauth2.py)
2. Visit following [site](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) Click on `Create Credentials > OAuth client ID` and continue until you get **client_id** and **client_secret**
3. Then run `oauth2.py --generate_oauth2_token` to get a **refresh_token**,

muttrc snippet:

```
set imap_authenticators="oauthbearer"
set imap_oauth_refresh_command="/path/to/oauth2.py --quiet --user=[email_address]\
    --client_id=[client_id] --client_secret=[client_secret]\
    --refresh_token=[refresh_token]"
```

Substitute *pop* or *smtp* for *imap* in the above example to configure for those.

---

Or create [application password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) and if it doesn't work either [Let less secure apps access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Comment: This seems to be a [link-only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) answer. You should provide context to all your links, otherwise the OP will have no idea what they are clicking into. Also, the link can break and the answer becomes worthless later.